# Server and client on same machine with no loopback

Tags: c++, linux, networking, loopback

I'm running  a server an a client on the same machine(linux). 
How do I force the packets to go through the network(switch) and not through the loopback?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Are you resolving by hostname? Not sure, but maybe providing the non-loopback IP address is enough?

Comment: Checked that. It's not enough.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're asking this on a programming site, I'll assume you have source code.

When you create the client-side socket, you can limit it to a specific interface. Usually you don't (you just call `connect()` without `bind()`ing it first) , and let the OS figure out the best outgoing interface, but this is not mandatory.

Comment: You sure it's on the client-side?

Comment: Well, the client initiates the connection, so tht's where you _must_ choose. The server may decide to listen only on the physical port, but that just means the server is unreachable if a client tries to connect via loopback.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about which parameter to change? I'm using the addrinfo struct and the getaddrinfo function

Comment: @Michael: Done; in hindsight the old text was indeed misleading.

Comment: Checked with tcpdump. The data still travels through the loopback interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option on both the client and the server sockets and give it the external NIC interface as parameter.

See: http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/10/code-snippet-sobindtodevice.html for an example

I am not sure this is enough - there might be a sanity check in the kernel IP stack to drop packets whose Ethernet destination and source are both you. There might be a sysctl to disable this check or you can compile your own kernel without the check for this specific test.

Comment: I tried that. It refuses to connect when I'm setting this setsockopt

Comment: Kindly refer to the rest of my answer regarding Linux kernel IP stack security mechanisms dropping your packet and what to do about it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try connecting via a proxy server?

Comment: I want to check the round trip latency without proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you have some device out there on a network whose job it is to send the data back to you. Normally, there is nothing that would do that. If you send the data out onto the network, you won't get it back.

If you have set something up to return the data to you, send the data to that, following whatever mechanism it supports.